# How can I FIND the last instance of a character in a string? (Google Sheets)

Tags: google-sheets, find, formula

I need a Google Sheet function that will return the position of the last instance of a particular character. Basically, FIND, but starting on the right.

For example, for the data set below, I need to return the position of the last dash.

```
ABC-DEF-GHI = 8
ABCD-EF-GH-IJK = 11
AB-C-DE-FGH-I-JK = 14
```

Thanks!

I don't know where to start. MID might work, but the file names are of different lengths and different formats. The files just generally end with - ***.png, and I need the asterisk. The string I need is also of variable length and can contain spaces (the string is the name of the student).

Comment: PSA: Do NOT share [spreadsheets](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/260455)/[images](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551) as the only source of data. Make sure to add input and expected output as **plain text table** to the question. [Click here](//webapps.stackexchange.com/a/161855) to create a table easily, which are **easier to copy/paste as well**. Your question may be closed, if it isn't self contained. [Your email address can also be accessed by the public](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/394304), if you share Google files.

Answer (score 3):

Here's a possible solution:

```
=len(regexextract(A1,".*-"))
```

It's essentially extracting everything up to the last dash and taking the length of the resulting string.

Comment: Works fine, thoug Google sheet should really have some handy reverse-search function for this.

Answer (score 0):

for the whole array try:

```
=INDEX(LEN(REGEXEXTRACT(A1:A3; "(.*-)")))
```

[image]